# Voice separation using FASST

Tags: speech-recognition

I want to increase voice recognition accuracy by speech separation in a car environment. The voice to be handled is a challenge, because noise, radio music and other speaker's voices may always be mixed together.

So I want to separate the voice into two parts, one is just my voice, the other is the defined general noise. For that, I train a speaker-dependent GMM module （just my voice） by HTK, and then separate the voices using FASST. Do you think this will work?

Answer (score 1):

For NMF I would use openblissart instead. Another good idea is to record in stereo if you are not doing that already.

You can most improvements from switching to DNN models instead of HMM and Kaldi, much more than you can get from any source separation. With DNN you can also do multistyle training, it will perform even better than noise separation. You can check CHIME experiment setup in Kaldi sources to see how to train noise-robust recognizer.